# Open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ (equipped with usual euclidian metric)

How can I show for $t>0$ that $B((x,y),t) \subseteq (x-t,x+t)\times(y-t,y+t)$ ?

It is pretty clear to me visually but proving it with the Euclidean metric I don't know. Is it safe to assume that if $(a,b)\in B((x,y),t)$ that $|a-x|<t$ and $|b-y|<t$. That might help but I don't know if I can assume that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $(a,b)\in B\bigl((x,y),t\bigr)$. Then $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<t^2$ and therefore each of the numbers $(x-a)^2$ and $(y-b)^2$ are smaller than $t^2$. In other words,$$|x-a|<t\quad\text{and}\quad|y-b|<t.$$And this is the same thing as asserting that$$a\in(x-t,x+t)\quad\text{and}\quad b\in(y-t,y+t).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $(a,b)\in B((x,y),t)$ then $|x-a|\leq \sqrt{|x-a|^2+|y-b|^2}<t$. Same for $|y-b|$.